# Center A Grid Of Thumbnails Within Responsive Container

Tags: html, css

I have dynamically generated thumbnails that will be inserted inside a container of fluid width. The thumbnails will have a set width/height of 150px and a margin of 5px. I want the tiles to be horizontally centered within the container, but I want each tile to line up below each other to form a grid.

I have written the following code but I am unable to get the thumbnails to be centered within the container. If I remove the `float:left;`, the thumbnails will be centered but the thumbnails are no longer lined up below each other to form a grid.

How would I modify the CSS to achieve a grid of thumbnails that are centered within a container of fluid width?

https://jsfiddle.net/bL7kfq5s/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="thumb"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  <div class="thumb"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  <div class="thumb"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  <div class="thumb"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  <div class="thumb"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  width: 600px; /* responsive width */
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.thumb {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 5px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please replace .thumb with this code

```
.thumb {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 5px 5px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: The thumbnails are no longer lined up in a grid. The 4th and 5th thumbnail is now centered to the container instead of lining up with the thumbs above.

Comment: try this peace of code along with the one above

.thumb:nth-child(1), .thumb:nth-child(4) {
    margin-left: 10%;
}

Comment: Sukesh -  I didn't see anything happen. Can you post a fiddle of it?

Comment: If I change the width of `.container`, the grid will break

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-wrapper whose width you can set relative to your main wrapper, and float the thumbs within the sub as below:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="subwrapper">
  <div class="thumb"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  <div class="thumb"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  <div class="thumb"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  <div class="thumb"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150"></div>
  <div class="thumb"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150"></div>
</div>
```

```
.subwrapper {
  width: 480px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/45sosd29/